# Golang mgo query only returns first object in query

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I´m trying to get a list of blog entries a certain user has authored but my query only returns the first entry created.

This is my User model

```
 type User struct {
  Id  bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"id"`
  Name string `json:"name"`
}
```

and my BlogEntry model

```
type BlogEntry struct {
  Id  bson.ObjectId  `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"id"`
  UserId bson.ObjectId `json:"user_id"`
  Title string `json:"title"`
}
```

And this is my query for fetching all blog entries for a certain user

```
  iter := service.Collection.Find(bson.M{"user_id": bson.ObjectIdHex(id)}).Iter()
```

Problem is, this only results in the FIRST entry for the user with the passed id.

I´ve checked the data and it seems correct, all the entries have a correct user_id field and so on.

Any ideas why I only get the first entry?

EDIT:

Complete implementation of my function that queries the entries.

```
func (service *BlogEntryService) GetEntryByUserId(id string) []models.BlogEntry {

      var entries []models.BlogEntry
      iter := service.Collection.Find(bson.M{"user_id": bson.ObjectIdHex(id)}).Iter()
      result := models.BlogEntry{}
        for iter.Next(&result) {
            entries = append(entries, result)
        }
      return entries
    }
```

Comment: Show the code that you use to iterate through the entries.

Comment: @XyMcXface Of course, updated the post.

Comment: Call iter.Close() after the loop and report the error returned, if any.  Also, you can write this as `err := service.Collection.Find(bson.M{"user_id": bson.ObjectIdHex(id)}).Iter().All(&entries)`.

Comment: @XyMcXface Thans for the suggestion, unfortunately the result was the same, only one of the entries was returned.

Comment: @XyMcXface It seems to something wrong the the actual query (or the stored data), if run the query on some other property than "event_id" it works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out, probably a beginner mistake.

I still don't know why it returned the first object, that´s still a bit weird.

But my mistake was not adding the "user_id" field as bson on the model.
So this:

```
type BlogEntry struct {
  Id  bson.ObjectId  `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"id"`
  UserId bson.ObjectId `json:"user_id"`
  Title string `json:"title"`
}
```

should have been:

```
 type BlogEntry struct {
      Id  bson.ObjectId  `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"id"`
      UserId bson.ObjectId `bson:"user_id" json:"user_id"`
      Title string `json:"title"`
    }
```

Now it works as expected!